# Microsoft Access query returning sequential numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there any way to create query in MS Access which returns sequential numbers of my choice? For example

```
10.1
10.2
10.3
10.4
10.5
```

or

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
```

or

```
2015-04-10 12:00
2015-04-10 13:00
2015-04-10 14:00
2015-04-10 15:00
2015-04-10 16:00
2015-04-10 17:00
2015-04-10 18:00
```

I can create temporary table with these values using VBA. I can also create my own VBA function which I put into a query. The question is: Is this possible with pure MS Access query? And if not, what would be the simplest and fastest approach?

EDIT: I don't have to avoid VBA, I just want to find short, clean, and efficient code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple Cartesian Query having a table with numbers from 0 to 9:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Number + 
    t2.Number * 10 + 
    t3.Number * 100 + 
    t4.Number * 1000 As Factor
FROM 
    tblNumber AS t1, 
    tblNumber AS t2,
    tblNumber AS t3, 
    tblNumber AS t4
```

or - if you only need small series - just a table with numbers from 0 to 99.

Then for your samples:

```
SELECT 
    10 + 0.1 * [Number] AS [Value]
FROM 
    tblNumber
WHERE 
    [Number] Between 1 And 5
```

and:

```
SELECT 
    [Number] * 10 AS [Value]
FROM 
    tblNumber
WHERE 
    [Number] Between 2 And 10
ORDER BY 
    [Number] * 10 Desc
```

and:

```
SELECT 
    DateAdd("h", [Number], #2015-04-10 12:00 PM#) AS [Date]
FROM 
    tblNumber
WHERE 
    [Number] Between 0 And 6
```

**Addendum**

A number series can also be built without a dedicated number table by using a system table as source:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    msysobjects AS Uno, 
    msysobjects AS Deca;
```

Comment: It seems like making small table with numbers is the only solution. This answer is basically the same as the one from shA.t but code looks cleaner. You both a right, but this answer looks better to me.

Comment: No it is not the only solution, see addendum.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a solution like this:

1. Make a table (name it `t`) like this:

   ```
   ID | i
   ---+---
   1  | 0
   2  | 1
   3  | 2
   4  | 3
   5  | 4
   6  | 5
   7  | 6
   8  | 7
   9  | 8
   10 | 9
   ```
2. Now use this table for all you need, for example make a query from `0` to `9999` use this query:

   ```
   SELECT 
       i1 + i2 * 10 + i3 * 100 + i4 * 1000 AS rowNo
   FROM 
       (SELECT 
           t1.i AS i1, t2.i AS i2 
        FROM 
           t AS t1, t AS t2) AS tt1, 
       (SELECT 
           t1.i AS i3, t2.i AS i4 
        FROM 
           t AS t1, t AS t2) AS tt2;
   ```
3. For example you can change `rowNo` formula to these:

   ```
   CDbl('10.'+CStr([i1]+[i2]*10+[i3]*100+[i4]*1000))   =>  10.1, 10.2, ...
   ```

   or

   ```
   (10000 - ([i1]+[i2]*10+[i3]*100+[i4]*1000)) * 10    => 100000, 99990, ... , 20, 10
   ```

   or

   ```
   DateAdd("h",[i1]+[i2]*10+[i3]*100+[i4]*1000,#4/10/2015 12:00:00 PM#)
   ```