# Generate multiple records using quantity in database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables

```
OrderTable: orderID<auto>, productName, qty

ItemTable: itemID<auto>, orderID, productName, location<default "shop">
```

OrderTable **one-to-many** relationship with ItemTable

I want to be able to generate item records by creating orders.

For example, I type following on OrderTable

```
orderID 1, productName paint, qty 3
```

And this will create three records on the ItemTable

```
itemID 1, orderID 1, productName paint, location shop
itemID 2, orderID 1, productName paint, location shop
itemID 3, orderID 1, productName paint, location shop
```

I have tried using inner join [repeat record asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526788/repeat-records-according-to-a-quantity-field)
but the solution does not produce distinct itemID, and as a result it is impossible to track individual items in the inventory.

I don't see any other possible designs. To track each individual items, I have to use item level records. It feels natural to auto generate items by typing in orders and quantities.

I am using **Microsoft Access** for this project.

Comment: By "generate records" do you mean you want to `INSERT` new records, or `SELECT` existing records? It's unclear what you _actually_ want to achieve.

Comment: If there is an interface in front of your DB, you could use that interface to loop from 1 to the  quantity.  Each loop will run 1 INSERT, which will increment the itemID.  So quantity == 3, it will run 3 INSERT statements, with exactly the same information in each statement.

Comment: As @Nic3500 said, use code to run INSERT sql action in loop structure.

Comment: Is ItemID an autonumber type? Can each order have multiple types of products?

Comment: @Dai I want to insert new records. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The example you referenced does not create records that can be 'tracked'. It generates 'virtual' records for purpose of report output to print some labels. If you want to 'track' line item then you must create actual records in table. One way to accomplish creating records is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use code to run INSERT sql action in loop structure. Dangers of doing this is that duplicate entries could be created if user accidentally clicks button more than once - if code is in button Click event. So this code example is very simple and does not deal with preventing duplication. The tricky part is actually figuring out what event to put code into.

Really should save product ID not descriptive name, and possibly the same for location.

If ItemID is an autonumber type, it will automatically generate.

```
For x = 1 to Me.tbxQty
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO ItemTable(OrderID, ProductID, Location) " & _
                      "VALUES(" & Me!OrderID & "," & Me!ProductID & ",'shop')"
Next
```

If you are going to use a line items detail table, then the product and quantity should not be in OrderTable. There should be OrderDate and CustomerID.

Comment: I have looked into the option of using vba to program a looped insert. However, this alternative design contains just a form that creates multiple items and do not save them to the underlying table. I avoided this method precisely to avoid duplicate creations as you have stated

Comment: I agree that OrderDate and CustomerID only for OrderTable is a better database design.

Comment: Location and Product name are used as primary keys for their corresponding tables. The only reason for this design is because I found that it is easier to understand context relevant names rather than IDs( row number in MS access)

Comment: I think you have answered my question. However, I will wait for a few days in case a sql solution pops up. Mean while I will improve my database design in the.